# Create Multiple Variables from a Function

Tags: python, function, variables

I want to create multiple variables from a function output without repeating the code in the function body.

Here's the current code:

```
def pizza(meat):
    pork = 'my favorite pizza is %s' % (meat)
    return(pork)

grub = pizza('Pepperoni')
print(grub)
```

It prints out:

```
my favorite pizza is Pepperoni
```

I want to create two variables with the content below:

```
my favorite pizza is Pepperoni
my favorite pizza is Salami
```

What do I do?

Any help would be appreciated. I struggle with functions and am new to programming.

Comment: Call the function twice?  It's not really clear what you're asking for here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class and a method instead of a function, like this:

```
class Pizza(object):
    def __init__(self, meat='Pepperoni'):
        self.meat = meat

    def i_like(self):
        print('my favorite pizza is %s' % (self.meat))
```

Running the script:

```
In: my_fav = Pizza()
In: my_fav.i_like()

Out: my favorite pizza is Pepperoni
------------------------------------
In: my_fav1 = Pizza('Salami')
In: my_fav1.i_like()

Out: my favorite pizza is Salami
```

Hope it helps.